# Javascript - Error While Reading parquet data from AWS s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, parquet

I am trying to read a parquet file from S3 . When testing the code from command line, i am getting this error. Can anyone see where i am going wrong?

```
 error in read parquet file  TypeError: client.getObject is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```
const { S3, HeadObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand }= require('@aws-sdk/client-s3')
const parquet = require("parquetjs-lite");
try {
      const client = new S3({region:"us-west-2"});

      const params = {
        Bucket: s3Bucket,
        Key: 'XXXXX' // here I am passing parquet file name
      };
      
      let reader = await parquet.ParquetReader.openS3(
        {s3ClientAWS, HeadObjectCommand, GetObjectCommand},
        params
      );
      
      // create a new cursor
      let cursor = reader.getCursor();
      
      // read all records from the file and print them
      let record = null;
      while (record = await cursor.next()) {
        console.log(record);
      }

      reader.close();
}catch (err) {
  console.log(" error in read parquet file ", err);
}
```

BTW my parquet files are stored on AWS S3 location (unlike in this test code). I still have to find solution to read parquet file from S3 bucket.

Any help, suggestions, code example will be highly appreciated.